# ExceptionHandler Nest can't resolve dependencies of the GetUserService. Please make sure that the argument Symbol(USER_REPOSITORY) at index [0]

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I'm trying to export a module but I'm having an error.

```
 ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the GetUserService (?). Please make sure that the argument Symbol(USER_REPOSITORY) at index [0] is available in the AuthUserModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is AuthUserModule a valid NestJS module?
- If Symbol(USER_REPOSITORY) is a provider, is it part of the current AuthUserModule?
- If Symbol(USER_REPOSITORY) is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AuthUserModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing Symbol(USER_REPOSITORY) */ ]
  })
```

I'm using these files.

**get-user.service.ts**

```
import { IApplicationServiceQuery } from '@lib-commons/application';
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GetUserQuery, USER_REPOSITORY } from '@app-auth/modules/user/application';
import { IUserRepository } from '@app-auth/modules/user/domain';
import { User } from '@app-auth/modules/user/domain/user';

@Injectable()
export class GetUserService implements IApplicationServiceQuery<GetUserQuery> {
  constructor(
    @Inject(USER_REPOSITORY) private userRepository: IUserRepository,
  ) {}

  process<T extends GetUserQuery>(query: T): Promise<User> {
    const { email } = query;

    const user = this.userRepository.getByEmailOrFail(email);

    return user;
  }
}
```

**get-user.query.ts**

```
import { IQuery } from '@lib-commons/domain';

export class GetUserQuery implements IQuery {
  email: string;

  constructor(props?: Partial<GetUserQuery>) {
    if (props) {
      Object.assign(this, props);
    }
  }
}
```

**injections-tokens.ts**

```
export const USER_REPOSITORY = Symbol('USER_REPOSITORY');
```

**user-repository.ts**

```
import { User } from '@app-auth/modules/user/domain';

export interface IUserRepository {
  getByEmailOrFail(email: string): Promise<User>;
  persist(user: User): Promise<void>;
}
```

**user.ts**

```
import { RolesEnum } from '@app-auth/modules/user/domain';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

export interface IUserSchema {
  id: number;
  uuid: string;
  email: string;
  username: string;
  password: string;
  enabled: boolean;
  createdAt: Date;
  updatedAt: Date;
  deletedAt: Date;
  roles: RolesEnum[];
}

export class User {
  private _entityRoot = {} as IUserSchema;

  constructor(schema?: IUserSchema) {
    if (schema) {
      this.hydrate(schema);
    }
  }

  get id(): number {
    return this._entityRoot.id;
  }

  get uuid(): string {
    return this._entityRoot.uuid;
  }

  get email(): string {
    return this._entityRoot.email;
  }

  get username(): string {
    return this._entityRoot.username;
  }

  get password(): string {
    return this._entityRoot.password;
  }

  get isEnabled(): boolean {
    return this._entityRoot.enabled;
  }

  get createdAt(): Date {
    return this._entityRoot.createdAt;
  }

  get updatedAt(): Date {
    return this._entityRoot.updatedAt;
  }

  get deletedAt(): Date {
    return this._entityRoot.deletedAt;
  }

  get roles(): RolesEnum[] {
    return this._entityRoot.roles;
  }

  protected hydrate(schema: IUserSchema): void {
    this._entityRoot = schema;
  }

  public entityRoot(): IUserSchema {
    return this._entityRoot;
  }

  public toPrimitives(): IUserSchema {
    return this._entityRoot;
  }

  public enabled(): void {
    this._entityRoot.enabled = true;
  }

  public disabled(): void {
    this._entityRoot.enabled = false;
  }

  public withRoles(roles: RolesEnum[]): void {
    this._entityRoot.roles = roles;
  }

  public initializeCredentials(
    email: string,
    username: string,
    password: string,
  ): void {
    this._entityRoot.email = email;
    this._entityRoot.username = username;
    this._entityRoot.password = password;
  }

  public async encryptPassword(hashSalt: number): Promise<void> {
    this._entityRoot.password = await bcrypt.hash(
      this._entityRoot.password,
      hashSalt,
    );
  }
}
```

**auth-user.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import {
  USER_REPOSITORY,
  CreateUserRootService,
  GetUserService,
} from '@app-auth/modules/user/application';
import {
  TypeOrmUserRepository,
  UserModuleFacade,
  UserEntity,
} from '@app-auth/modules/user/infrastructure';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserEntity])],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [
    GetUserService,
    UserModuleFacade,
    CreateUserRootService,
    {
      provide: USER_REPOSITORY,
      useClass: TypeOrmUserRepository,
    },
  ],
  exports: [UserModuleFacade],
})
export class AuthUserModule {}
```

I don't know but I think is important since the get-users.service.ts is used here too.

**user-module.facade.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GetUserService, GetUserQuery } from '@app-auth/modules/user/application';

@Injectable()
export class UserModuleFacade {
  constructor(private readonly getUserService: GetUserService) {}

  getUserByEmail(getUserQuery: GetUserQuery) {
    return this.getUserService.process(getUserQuery);
  }
}
```

I tried to add fowardRef on the constructor of the service but didn't work.